# Media Capabilities property not specified

Tags: android

I run `./gradlew :app:lint` task to generate a report.

One of them is `Media Capabilities property not specified`：

../../src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6: The app accesses MediaStore.Video, but is missing a  tag with a android.content.MEDIA_CAPABILITIES declaration

```
  3   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  4   package="com.example.myapp">
  5 
  6   <application                                                                                      
  7     android:name=".App"
  8     android:allowBackup="false"
  9     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

In Android 12 and higher, an app that opens media files should explicitly specify media formats that it doesn't support, so the OS can provide a transcoded file instead.
To suppress this error, use the issue id "MediaCapabilities" as explained in the Suppressing Warnings and Errors section.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

I am not using any media capabilities in my app, and will still get this lint issue.

I simply suppressed the error to "fix" it. Seems like a false positive with Android Lint.

```xml
<application
    tools:ignore="MediaCapabilities">
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're getting the same warning and we don't have any video in our app - at least directly. I found [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195242930), they state that it might be from a library you're using. Until a better solution has been made by Google I think the best would be to just ignore it (as suggested by Marius Kohmann) if you're certain you're not using video in your app.